# Student Grading Program C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program in C++ that reads an sample input like below from a text file:
    Sample Input

```
    7 10
    William Horde AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA ;
    John Doe AA AA AA FF AA AA AA AA AA AA ;
    Hermann Straus AA AA AA AA AA BB NA AA AA AA ;
    Patrick Doe CC CC DC CC CB CC DC CC CC CC ;
    Xhulia Abazi AA BB BB BA CB BB CB CC BB AA;
    John Trki CC BB DC DD DD DD BB AA BB CC ;
    Julien Torfelt NA FD FD DD DC DC DC DD DD ;
```

In the first line are given the number of student 0

Below is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ofstream>

using namespace std;
void getData(char fnames[], char lnames[], string grades[], int &n, int &m);

int main()
{
    char fnames[100]; 
    char lnames[100]; 
    string grades[100]; int n,m;

    getData(fnames,lnames, grades , n, m);
    return 0;
}


void getData(char fnames[],char lnames[], string grades[], int &n, int &m)
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    fin>>n; // read number of students
    fin>>m; // read number of courses
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fin>>fnames;
        fin>>lnames;

        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            fin>>grades[j];
            if(grades[j]=="AA") sum = sum + 4.0;
            else if(grades[j]=="BA") sum = sum + 3.5;
            else if(grades[j]=="BB") sum = sum + 3.0;
            else if(grades[j]=="CB") sum = sum + 2.5;
            else if(grades[j]=="CC") sum = sum + 2.0;
            else if(grades[j]=="DC") sum = sum + 1.5;
            else if(grades[j]=="DD") sum = sum + 1.0;
            else if(grades[j]=="FD") sum = sum + 0.5;
            else sum = sum + 0.0; //FF , NA    
        }
    }        
}
```

How can I make my program to works correctly ?

Comment: what issues you have?

Comment: You don't set sum at zero when you compute grades for students.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a terminating semicolon, which you don't take into account. You'd better discard everything in a line after you've read all the grades. Just skip through the end of line with `istream::ignore`:

```
    // .............
        float avg = sum / m;
        cout<<"CGPA for "<<fnames<<" "<<lnames<<" is = "<<avg<<endl;; 
        fin.ignore(10, '\n');  // <------------------------------------ add this line
    }        
}
```

Second, you have to reset your `sum` for every new student. So move your `sum` initialization into the students loop:

```
    fin>>n; // read number of students
    fin>>m; // read number of courses
    //double sum = 0.0;        // <------------------------------------ remove from here
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;      // <------------------------------------ put here
        fin>>fnames;
        fin>>lnames;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with the code is ';' at the end of the line in the file is not read.

The program failed to get the ';' in fin , So that when  the loop continues to fin >> fnames** read the colon , and then the next fin continues the firstname in the second line as the lnames .

The corrected code for getData Function is ,

```
void getData(char fnames[],char lnames[], string grades[], int &n, int &m)
{
   ifstream fin("file.txt");
   char getColon[2] ; //added 
   fin>>n; // read number of students
   fin>>m; // read number of courses
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
   double sum = 0.0;
      fin>>fnames;
      fin>>lnames;

      for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
      {
         fin>>grades[j];
         if(grades[j]=="AA") sum = sum + 4.0;
         else if(grades[j]=="BA") sum = sum + 3.5;
         else if(grades[j]=="BB") sum = sum + 3.0;
         else if(grades[j]=="CB") sum = sum + 2.5;
         else if(grades[j]=="CC") sum = sum + 2.0;
         else if(grades[j]=="DC") sum = sum + 1.5;
         else if(grades[j]=="DD") sum = sum + 1.0;
         else if(grades[j]=="FD") sum = sum + 0.5;
         else sum = sum + 0.0; //FF , NA    
      }
      fin >> getColon ; //Added 
      float avg = sum / m;
      cout<<"CGPA for "<<fnames<<" "<<lnames<<" is = "<<avg<<endl; 
   }        
}
```

The line `fin >> getColon ; //Added` in the above code will get the colon as a tweak , and the code flow continues .

The Exact output for the above code is,

```
CGPA for William Horde is = 4
CGPA for John Doe is = 3.6
CGPA for Hermann Straus is = 3.5
CGPA for Patrick Doe is = 1.95
CGPA for Xhulia Abazi is = 2.65
CGPA for Trki CC is = 1.95
CGPA for Torfelt NA is = 0.85
```

Also initialize the `sum` variable inside the first for loop , so that it will be reset for every student before calculating.